# Stepwise regression with a huge matrix for y

Tags: r, regression, model-comparison

Aim is to find the best model. I use stepwise regression for it. But I've got a problem. When I try this:

```
library("MASS")
foreach (i=1:20000) %do% {
Ge <- bigGeneMatrix[i,]
fit <- lm(Ge ~ geneA + geneB + geneC + geneD + ... + geneX + (1|Patient),
data = master)
step <- stepAIC(fit, direction = "both")
results[i] <- step$anova }
```

There comes something strange out.

```
Step:  AIC=-268.58
Ge ~ ((geneA + geneB + geneC + geneD + ... + geneX + 
(1 | Patient)) - 1 |  Patient)

Start:  AIC=-596.19
Ge ~ ((geneA + geneB + geneC + geneD + ... + geneX + 
(1 | Patient)) - 1 |  Patient)


Step:  AIC=-603.22
Ge ~ ((geneA + geneB + geneC + geneD + ... + geneX + 
(1 | Patient)) - 1 |  Patient)
```

The outcome is always the same model. Only AIC differs. I also tried the *leaps()* function and *regsubsets()*, but it also doesn't show the result I'd like to have. 
I think the problem is that I have a big matrix with many different genes for *y* ( y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = abc).
I'd like to have something like this as result:

```
Ge ~ geneA + geneD + geneX
```

This is the best model which has the lowest AIC for example.

How can I get it?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/11849

Comment: You use mixed effects model syntax with `lm`. Apparently, you actually want `lme4::lmer`.

Comment: When I use lmer, step <- stepAIC(fit, direction = "both") doesn't work anymore. What to do? @Roland